# Rails associations - how can I set up associations for different varieties of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-models

I'm creating a web app which consists of schools, courses, students, and teachers.

A school can have many courses and a course has one teacher and many students.

The problem I am running into is that a single user could be a teacher of one course, but a student in another course (or even a student or teacher in a course in a different school).  I don't want to create a model for teachers and a separate model for students because I would like to track all my users in one place.  There is an enrollment table which lists which users are enrolled as students in a course.

I would like to do something like the following:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :students :through enrollments
  has_many :teachers :through courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :teacher
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students :through enrollments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :schools
end
```

But if I have only a users table and not two separate students and teachers tables, this won't work.

Instead, I would have to do something like

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users [that are teachers]
  has_many :users :through enrollments [that are students]
end
```

How can I set up my model and associations to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use inheritance.

Teachers and students are inherited from the users model. You can consult http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html for further information. Be sure to create a "type" column or equivalent in your User table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Student < User
end

class Teacher < User
end
```

Rails will treat them individually, but they will still exist in the User table.Let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I want to create a type column in my user table because the same user can sometimes be a student and sometimes be a teacher.  For instance, you can teach one course while being a student in a different course.

Comment: I think sohaib is right here. You can create a type column, and not have to worry about it at all. The object that you receive from Active Record will either be a Student or Teacher depending on the type. Its just another layer of abstraction.

Comment: Will this allow the same user to be both a student and a teacher?

Comment: You could have two entries for a same individual, I.e. one as a student and one as a teacher. This also makes sense because, you'd most probably be having separate logic for the two. Most School/college portals treat the 2 differently as well.

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but it should work if you add the `class_name` to your relation with "User":

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :students :through enrollments, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :teachers :through courses, :class_name => "User"
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :teacher, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students :through enrollments, , :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :schools
end
```

Comment: `class_name` is actually ignored on `:through` associations. Along with `primary_key` and `foreign_key`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `teachers_id` column to `courses` and use `belongs_to` instead of `has_one`. Then add a `class_name` option.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :students :through enrollments
  has_many :teachers :through courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students :through enrollments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :schools, :through enrollments
  has_many :teachers, :through :courses
end
```