# Rails 3 - correct way to give id for belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: **User** and **Teacher**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :password                                                               
  attr_accessible :user_login,                                                           
                  :user_role,
                  :password,
                  :teacher_attributes

  has_one :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher                                                  
end

# Table name: teachers
#
#  id                  :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id             :integer
#  teacher_last_name   :string(255)
#  teacher_first_name  :string(255)
#  teacher_middle_name :string(255)
#  teacher_birthday    :date
#  teacher_sex         :string(255)
#  teacher_category    :string(255)
#  created_at          :datetime
#  updated_at          :datetime

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :teacher_last_name,
                  :teacher_first_name,
                  :teacher_middle_name,
                  :teacher_birthday,
                  :teacher_sex,
                  :teacher_category

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Also I have a method in my controller which should create user and then new teacher. But doesn't work correctly, because I don't pass an `id` there.

My controller

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  def create_teacher
    user_errors, teacher_errors, redirect_path = nil, nil, nil 

    params[:user][:user_role] = "teacher"
    user = User.new(params[:user])                           #Problem is here

    if user.save
      redirect_path = admins_users_of_system_path
      flash[:success] = "Teacher created!"
    else
      redirect_path = admins_new_teacher_path
      user_errors = user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence                                     
      teacher_errors = user.teacher.errors.full_messages.to_sentence if user.teacher
    end

    errors_arr = [user_errors, teacher_errors].compact
    flash[:error] = errors_arr if errors_arr.present? 
    redirect_to redirect_path
  end
end
```

I have such code in controller because i want to grab all errors from user and teacher.

**Error**

```
["Teacher user can't be blank", "User can't be blank"]

utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: Hsw9BGOMb37cku6R2aAZsXkYaU5DFZqlUML4yZjqxI0=
user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  teacher_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    teacher_last_name: Popov
    teacher_first_name: Igor
    teacher_middle_name: Yurevich
    teacher_sex: m
    teacher_birthday: 28.08.1991
    teacher_category: Something 1
  user_login: schoolh_MXWTQ
  password: eviRDyalXnHlK6q
  user_role: teacher
commit: Создать
controller: admins
action: create_teacher
```

How can I create a teacher and an user in same time correctly? How should I pass it an id?

Comment: What error are you getting? What does your view look like?

Comment: Added the text of error in my post.

Comment: You create a teacher from an existing User? Or do you create the user in here too? What I mean is, do transform a user into a teacher?

Comment: I try to create user AND teacher.

Comment: What params does it show on the error page?

Comment: Also, it looks like you have no teacher.save, so you won't be creating both?

Comment: I updated my post, and now you can see my params.

Comment: I WANT to create user and teacher in same time bu `User.new(params[:user])` thats why i give User model access to teacher_attributes.

Comment: Ah, but there are no teacher attributes, because there is no teacher yet!

I get your frustration here. It seems very natural to create a type of user and in the process create the underlying user instance. I wrote the same questin here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006918/rails-user-heirarchies-classes-associations-polymorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach to this is to simply create the User on the first go round, including the role of teacher. Then the admin fills in a second form with the profile details, a "Fill in your profile" if you will (teacher model would still contain this.)

Either way, you'll probably want the delegates_to method for accessing methods http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/Module/delegate

Also, however you do it, you might just consider leaving the attr_accessible out until the thing is otherwise working properly.

But if you find a way to create them both at once, I'll be the first to copy you!

Comment: Ow! Your way with 2 different forms makes sense! I thought that there was easy way to save 2 models at once... Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, thanks-sortof! You bumped me to two new privaledges. But... I'd really like to know how to do what you were trying! I want a teacher to be able to sign up, and add teacher-specific info at the same time, because I also have student users.

Comment: I think, i found how to do that. I can share with you my result. You can write me your email if you want.

Comment: lol, no, 'cool' was not part of the email. It's just plain 'ed.jones@gmail.com' or if you prefer, edjones@openhistoryproject.org

Answer (score 0):

i think prob is params u give got wrong.
right way should be:**params[:user]['user_role'] = "teacher"**

Comment: once i encounter this error,while i changed to params[:user]['user_role'] = "teacher",it works.just experience.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
As I said in the comment:

Try:

```
user = User.create(params[:user])
```

instead of User.new

Comment: As i understand, `user = User.new(params[:user])` should create a teacher because it have access to `teacher_attribute` in User model. Problem is that i don't know how add user_id for a teacher correctly.

Comment: The user does not have an id until you save it. Im not sure how it works with accessible but you do not include user_id in your list of accessible attributes in teacher

Comment: I think maybe you should use User.create(params) instead of User.new(params),
I think it saves them right away and that is how they do it on
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Problem is that it cannot be saves because teacher needs user_id.

Comment: Is the user_id attribute accessible to you user model?

Comment: No, because i don't think that this is safe.